# Meteor: Dependency Hell with atmosphere packages regarding `accounts-base` when I try to update meteor to version 1.5.1

Tags: meteor

I try to update my meteor project but when I try to do via `meteor update` or via `meteor update --all-packages` or even via `meteor update --allow-incompatible-update` I get the following error:

```
error: No version of accounts-base satisfies all constraints: @1.3.1, @=1.3.0, @1.3.1
Constraints on package "accounts-base":
* accounts-base@1.3.1 <- top level
* accounts-base@=1.3.0 <- top level
* accounts-base@1.3.1 <- top level
* accounts-base@1.3.1 <- accounts-password 1.4.0
* accounts-base@1.2.14 <- service-configuration 1.0.11
* accounts-base@1.3.0 <- accounts-facebook 1.2.1
* accounts-base@1.3.0 <- accounts-google 1.2.0
* accounts-base@1.3.0 <- accounts-twitter 1.3.0
* accounts-base@1.0.0 <- matb33:collection-hooks 0.7.5
* accounts-base@1.0.1 <- pauli:accounts-linkedin 1.0.0
```

Do you have any idea how to fix all constraints?

## Edit1

The `./meteor/packages` contains:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.1.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.18                   # The database Meteor supports right now
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.3.4   # CSS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.8.0              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.2.3            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

react-meteor-data
alanning:roles
fourseven:scss
twbs:bootstrap
accounts-password@1.3.6
service-configuration@1.0.11
accounts-facebook@1.2.0
accounts-github@1.3.0
accounts-google@1.2.0
themeteorchef:bert
fortawesome:fontawesome
aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.0
audit-argument-checks@1.0.7
ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7
dynamic-import
static-html
session
accounts-twitter
tap:i18n
momentjs:moment
rzymek:moment-locale-el
http
matb33:collection-hooks
pauli:accounts-linkedin
jquery
oauth
facebook-oauth
accounts-base
accounts-oauth
abernix:standard-minifier-js
```

Is seems it has no version specification over `accounts-base`

## Edit 2

The only reference for `accounts-base@=1.3.0` is on file named `./.meteor/local/resolder-result-cache.json`:

```json
{"lastInput":{"dependencies":["meteor-base","mobile-experience","mongo","reactive-var","tracker","standard-minifier-css","es5-shim","ecmascript","shell-server","react-meteor-data","alanning:roles","fourseven:scss","twbs:bootstrap","accounts-password","service-configuration","accounts-facebook","accounts-github","accounts-google","themeteorchef:bert","fortawesome:fontawesome","aldeed:collection2-core","audit-argument-checks","ddp-rate-limiter","dynamic-import","static-html","session","accounts-twitter","tap:i18n","momentjs:moment","rzymek:moment-locale-el","http","matb33:collection-hooks","pauli:accounts-linkedin","jquery","oauth","facebook-oauth","accounts-base","accounts-oauth","standard-minifier-js"],"constraints":["meteor-base@1.1.0","mobile-experience@1.0.4","mongo@1.1.18","reactive-var@1.0.11","tracker@1.1.3","standard-minifier-css@1.3.4","es5-shim@4.6.15","ecmascript@0.8.0","shell-server@0.2.3","react-meteor-data","alanning:roles","fourseven:scss","twbs:bootstrap","accounts-password@1.3.6","service-configuration@1.0.11","accounts-facebook@1.2.0","accounts-github@1.3.0","accounts-google@1.2.0","themeteorchef:bert","fortawesome:fontawesome","aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.0","audit-argument-checks@1.0.7","ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7","dynamic-import","static-html","session","accounts-twitter","tap:i18n","momentjs:moment","rzymek:moment-locale-el","http","matb33:collection-hooks","pauli:accounts-linkedin","jquery","oauth","facebook-oauth","accounts-base","accounts-oauth","standard-minifier-js","accounts-base@=1.3.0","local-test:accounts-base@=1.3.0","accounts-oauth@=1.1.15","local-test:accounts-oauth@=1.1.15","accounts-base@1.3.0","accounts-facebook@1.2.0","accounts-github@1.3.0","accounts-google@1.2.0","accounts-meetup@1.3.0","accounts-meteor-developer@1.3.0","accounts-oauth@1.1.15","accounts-password@1.3.6","accounts-twitter@1.3.0","accounts-ui-unstyled@1.2.1","accounts-ui@1.1.9","accounts-weibo@1.2.0","allow-deny@1.0.5","appcache@1.0.12","audit-argument-checks@1.0.7","autopublish@1.0.7","autoupdate@1.3.12","babel-compiler@6.19.1","babel-runtime@1.0.1","base64@1.0.10","binary-heap@1.0.10","boilerplate-generator@1.1.0","browser-policy-common@1.0.11","browser-policy-content@1.1.0","browser-policy-framing@1.1.0","browser-policy@1.1.0","caching-compiler@1.1.9","callback-hook@1.0.10","check@1.2.5","coffeescript-test-helper@1.0.8","constraint-solver@1.1.1","crosswalk@1.7.1","ddp-client@1.3.4","ddp-common@1.2.8","ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7","ddp-server@1.3.14","ddp@1.2.5","deps@1.0.12","diff-sequence@1.0.7","disable-oplog@1.0.7","dynamic-import@0.1.0","ecmascript-runtime-client@0.4.1","ecmascript-runtime-server@0.4.1","ecmascript-runtime@0.4.1","ecmascript@0.8.0","ejson@1.0.13","email@1.2.1","es5-shim@4.6.15","facebook-config-ui@1.0.0","facebook-oauth@1.3.1","facts@1.0.9","fastclick@1.0.13","force-ssl-common@1.0.14","force-ssl@1.0.14","geojson-utils@1.0.10","github-config-ui@1.0.0","github-oauth@1.2.0","google-config-ui@1.0.0","google-oauth@1.2.4","hot-code-push@1.0.4","http@1.2.12","id-map@1.0.9","insecure@1.0.7","jquery@1.11.10","jshint@1.1.7","jsparse@1.0.10","launch-screen@1.1.1","less@2.7.9","livedata@1.0.18","localstorage@1.1.0","logging@1.1.17","logic-solver@2.0.7","markdown@1.0.12","meetup-config-ui@1.0.0","meetup-oauth@1.0.1","meteor-base@1.1.0","meteor-developer-config-ui@1.0.0","meteor-developer-oauth@1.2.0","meteor@1.6.1","meyerweb-reset@1.0.7","minifier-css@1.2.16","minifier-js@2.1.0","minimongo@1.2.0","mobile-experience@1.0.4","mobile-status-bar@1.0.14","modules-runtime@0.8.0","modules@0.9.0","mongo-id@1.0.6","mongo-livedata@1.0.12","mongo@1.1.18","npm-bcrypt@0.9.2","npm-mongo@2.2.24","oauth-encryption@1.2.1","oauth@1.1.13","oauth1@1.1.11","oauth2@1.1.11","observe-sequence@1.0.16","ordered-dict@1.0.9","package-stats-opt-out@1.0.7","package-version-parser@3.0.10","promise@0.8.9","random@1.0.10","rate-limit@1.0.8","reactive-dict@1.1.9","reactive-var@1.0.11","reload-safetybelt@1.0.12","reload@1.1.11","retry@1.0.9","routepolicy@1.0.12","service-configuration@1.0.11","session@1.1.7","sha@1.0.9","shell-server@0.2.3","showdown@1.0.8","srp@1.0.10","standard-minifier-css@1.3.4","standard-minifier-js@2.1.0","standard-minifiers@1.1.0","stylus@2.513.9","test-helpers@1.0.11","test-in-browser@1.0.13","test-in-console@1.0.15","test-server-tests-in-console-once@1.0.11","tinytest-harness@0.0.4","tinytest@1.0.12","tracker@1.1.3","twitter-config-ui@1.0.0","twitter-oauth@1.2.0","underscore-tests@1.0.8","underscore@1.0.10","url@1.1.0","webapp-hashing@1.0.9","webapp@1.3.16","weibo-config-ui@1.0.0","weibo-oauth@1.2.0","xmlbuilder@2.5.15"],"previousSolution":{"accounts-base":"1.3.0","accounts-facebook":"1.2.0","accounts-github":"1.3.0","accounts-google":"1.2.0","accounts-oauth":"1.1.15","accounts-password":"1.3.7","accounts-twitter":"1.3.0","alanning:roles":"1.2.16","aldeed:collection2-core":"2.0.1","aldeed:simple-schema":"1.3.3","allow-deny":"1.0.5","audit-argument-checks":"1.0.7","autoupdate":"1.3.12","babel-compiler":"6.19.2","babel-runtime":"1.0.1","base64":"1.0.10","binary-heap":"1.0.10","blaze":"2.3.2","blaze-tools":"1.0.10","boilerplate-generator":"1.1.0","caching-compiler":"1.1.9","caching-html-compiler":"1.1.2","callback-hook":"1.0.10","cfs:http-methods":"0.0.32","check":"1.2.5","coffeescript":"1.0.17","ddp":"1.2.5","ddp-client":"1.3.4","ddp-common":"1.2.8","ddp-rate-limiter":"1.0.7","ddp-server":"1.3.14","deps":"1.0.12","diff-sequence":"1.0.7","dynamic-import":"0.1.1","ecmascript":"0.8.0","ecmascript-runtime":"0.4.1","ecmascript-runtime-client":"0.4.2","ecmascript-runtime-server":"0.4.1","ejson":"1.0.13","email":"1.2.3","es5-shim":"4.6.15","facebook-oauth":"1.3.1","fastclick":"1.0.13","fortawesome:fontawesome":"4.7.0","fourseven:scss":"4.5.0","geojson-utils":"1.0.10","github-oauth":"1.2.0","google-oauth":"1.2.4","hot-code-push":"1.0.4","html-tools":"1.0.11","htmljs":"1.0.11","http":"1.2.12","id-map":"1.0.9","jquery":"1.11.10","launch-screen":"1.1.1","livedata":"1.0.18","localstorage":"1.1.0","logging":"1.1.17","matb33:collection-hooks":"0.8.4","meteor":"1.6.1","meteor-base":"1.1.0","meteorspark:util":"0.2.0","minifier-css":"1.2.16","minifier-js":"2.1.0","minimongo":"1.2.1","mobile-experience":"1.0.4","mobile-status-bar":"1.0.14","modules":"0.9.1","modules-runtime":"0.8.0","momentjs:moment":"2.18.1","mongo":"1.1.18","mongo-id":"1.0.6","npm-bcrypt":"0.9.3","npm-mongo":"2.2.24","oauth":"1.1.13","oauth1":"1.1.11","oauth2":"1.1.11","observe-sequence":"1.0.16","ordered-dict":"1.0.9","pauli:accounts-linkedin":"2.1.2","pauli:linkedin-oauth":"1.1.0","promise":"0.8.9","raix:eventemitter":"0.1.3","random":"1.0.10","rate-limit":"1.0.8","react-meteor-data":"0.2.12","reactive-dict":"1.1.9","reactive-var":"1.0.11","reload":"1.1.11","retry":"1.0.9","routepolicy":"1.0.12","rzymek:moment-locale-el":"2.14.1","service-configuration":"1.0.11","session":"1.1.7","sha":"1.0.9","shell-server":"0.2.3","spacebars":"1.0.15","spacebars-compiler":"1.1.2","srp":"1.0.10","standard-minifier-css":"1.3.4","standard-minifier-js":"2.1.0","static-html":"1.2.2","tap:i18n":"1.8.2","templating":"1.3.2","templating-compiler":"1.3.2","templating-runtime":"1.3.2","templating-tools":"1.1.2","themeteorchef:bert":"2.1.2","tmeasday:check-npm-versions":"0.3.1","tracker":"1.1.3","twbs:bootstrap":"3.3.6","twitter-oauth":"1.2.0","ui":"1.0.13","underscore":"1.0.10","url":"1.1.0","webapp":"1.3.16","webapp-hashing":"1.0.9"}},"lastOutput":{"neededToUseUnanticipatedPrereleases":false,"answer":{"accounts-base":"1.3.0","accounts-facebook":"1.2.0","accounts-github":"1.3.0","accounts-google":"1.2.0","accounts-oauth":"1.1.15","accounts-password":"1.3.7","accounts-twitter":"1.3.0","alanning:roles":"1.2.16","aldeed:collection2-core":"2.0.1","aldeed:simple-schema":"1.3.3","allow-deny":"1.0.5","audit-argument-checks":"1.0.7","autoupdate":"1.3.12","babel-compiler":"6.19.2","babel-runtime":"1.0.1","base64":"1.0.10","binary-heap":"1.0.10","blaze":"2.3.2","blaze-tools":"1.0.10","boilerplate-generator":"1.1.0","caching-compiler":"1.1.9","caching-html-compiler":"1.1.2","callback-hook":"1.0.10","cfs:http-methods":"0.0.32","check":"1.2.5","coffeescript":"1.0.17","ddp":"1.2.5","ddp-client":"1.3.4","ddp-common":"1.2.8","ddp-rate-limiter":"1.0.7","ddp-server":"1.3.14","deps":"1.0.12","diff-sequence":"1.0.7","dynamic-import":"0.1.1","ecmascript":"0.8.0","ecmascript-runtime":"0.4.1","ecmascript-runtime-client":"0.4.2","ecmascript-runtime-server":"0.4.1","ejson":"1.0.13","email":"1.2.3","es5-shim":"4.6.15","facebook-oauth":"1.3.1","fastclick":"1.0.13","fortawesome:fontawesome":"4.7.0","fourseven:scss":"4.5.0","geojson-utils":"1.0.10","github-oauth":"1.2.0","google-oauth":"1.2.4","hot-code-push":"1.0.4","html-tools":"1.0.11","htmljs":"1.0.11","http":"1.2.12","id-map":"1.0.9","isobuild:compiler-plugin":"1.0.0","isobuild:dynamic-import":"1.5.0","isobuild:isopack-2":"1.0.0","isobuild:minifier-plugin":"1.0.0","jquery":"1.11.10","launch-screen":"1.1.1","livedata":"1.0.18","localstorage":"1.1.0","logging":"1.1.17","matb33:collection-hooks":"0.8.4","meteor":"1.6.1","meteor-base":"1.1.0","meteorspark:util":"0.2.0","minifier-css":"1.2.16","minifier-js":"2.1.0","minimongo":"1.2.1","mobile-experience":"1.0.4","mobile-status-bar":"1.0.14","modules":"0.9.1","modules-runtime":"0.8.0","momentjs:moment":"2.18.1","mongo":"1.1.18","mongo-id":"1.0.6","npm-bcrypt":"0.9.3","npm-mongo":"2.2.24","oauth":"1.1.13","oauth1":"1.1.11","oauth2":"1.1.11","observe-sequence":"1.0.16","ordered-dict":"1.0.9","pauli:accounts-linkedin":"2.1.2","pauli:linkedin-oauth":"1.1.0","promise":"0.8.9","raix:eventemitter":"0.1.3","random":"1.0.10","rate-limit":"1.0.8","react-meteor-data":"0.2.12","reactive-dict":"1.1.9","reactive-var":"1.0.11","reload":"1.1.11","retry":"1.0.9","routepolicy":"1.0.12","rzymek:moment-locale-el":"2.14.1","service-configuration":"1.0.11","session":"1.1.7","sha":"1.0.9","shell-server":"0.2.3","spacebars":"1.0.15","spacebars-compiler":"1.1.2","srp":"1.0.10","standard-minifier-css":"1.3.4","standard-minifier-js":"2.1.0","static-html":"1.2.2","tap:i18n":"1.8.2","templating":"1.3.2","templating-compiler":"1.3.2","templating-runtime":"1.3.2","templating-tools":"1.1.2","themeteorchef:bert":"2.1.2","tmeasday:check-npm-versions":"0.3.1","tracker":"1.1.3","twbs:bootstrap":"3.3.6","twitter-oauth":"1.2.0","ui":"1.0.13","underscore":"1.0.10","url":"1.1.0","webapp":"1.3.16","webapp-hashing":"1.0.9"}}}
```

## Edit 3:

I tried to remove the meteor's local cache via:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.meteor/cache
```

And run afterwards:

```
meteor update
```

And I get the same problem.

## Edit 4:

For extra info:

I started my meteor app:

```
meteor run
```

And stoped int by pushint `Ctrl`+`C`.

I run the following command:

```
for p in `meteor list | grep '^[a-z]' | awk '{ print $1"@"$2 }'`; do echo "$p"; meteor show "$p" | grep -E '^  [a-z]'; echo; done > ~/dependencies.txt
```

Which produced:

```
accounts-base@1.3.0+: not found
accounts-facebook@1.2.0*: not found
accounts-oauth@1.1.15+: not found
accounts-password@1.3.7*: not found
ecmascript@0.8.0*: not found
facebook-oauth@1.3.1*: not found
fourseven:scss@4.5.0*: not found
mongo@1.1.18*: not found
pauli:accounts-linkedin@2.1.2*: not found
shell-server@0.2.3*: not found
standard-minifier-js@2.1.0*: not found
themeteorchef:bert@2.1.2*: not found
```

And a file named `dependencies.txt` containing:

```
accounts-base@1.3.0+

accounts-facebook@1.2.0*

accounts-google@1.2.0
  accounts-base@1.3.0
  accounts-oauth@1.1.15
  accounts-ui@1.1.9 (weak dependency)
  google-config-ui@1.0.0 (weak dependency)
  google-oauth@1.2.4
  random@1.0.10
  underscore@1.0.10

accounts-oauth@1.1.15+

accounts-password@1.3.7*

accounts-twitter@1.3.0
  accounts-base@1.3.0
  accounts-oauth@1.1.15
  accounts-ui@1.1.9 (weak dependency)
  http@1.2.12
  twitter-config-ui@1.0.0 (weak dependency)
  twitter-oauth@1.2.0
  underscore@1.0.10

alanning:roles@1.2.16
  accounts-base@1.2.1
  blaze@2.1.3 (weak dependency)
  check@1.0.6
  mongo@1.1.2
  tracker@1.0.9
  underscore@1.0.4

aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.1
  ecmascript@0.6.1
  ejson@1.0.0
  insecure@1.0.0 (weak dependency)
  isobuild:isopack-2@1.0.0
  minimongo@1.0.0
  mongo@1.0.4
  raix:eventemitter@0.1.3
  tmeasday:check-npm-versions@0.3.1
  underscore@1.0.0

audit-argument-checks@1.0.7

ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7
  rate-limit@1.0.7

dynamic-import@0.1.1
  browser-policy-content@1.1.0 (weak dependency)
  check@1.2.5
  ddp@1.2.5
  ecmascript@0.8.0
  isobuild:dynamic-import@1.5.0
  isobuild:isopack-2@1.0.0
  modules@0.9.1
  promise@0.8.9

ecmascript@0.8.0*

es5-shim@4.6.15
  modules@0.7.7

facebook-oauth@1.3.1*

fortawesome:fontawesome@4.7.0

fourseven:scss@4.5.0*

http@1.2.12
  ecmascript@0.6.3
  isobuild:isopack-2@1.0.0
  underscore@1.0.10
  url@1.1.0

jquery@1.11.10
  modules@0.7.7

matb33:collection-hooks@0.8.4
  accounts-base@1.2.8 (weak dependency)
  ejson@1.0.12
  minimongo@1.0.17
  mongo@1.1.9_1
  tracker@1.0.15
  underscore@1.0.9

meteor-base@1.1.0
  ddp@1.2.5
  dynamic-import@0.1.0
  hot-code-push@1.0.4
  livedata@1.0.18
  underscore@1.0.10
  webapp@1.3.16

mobile-experience@1.0.4
  fastclick@1.0.11
  launch-screen@1.0.11
  mobile-status-bar@1.0.12

momentjs:moment@2.18.1

mongo@1.1.18*

oauth@1.1.13
  base64@1.0.10
  check@1.2.4
  localstorage@1.0.12
  logging@1.1.17
  mongo@1.1.15
  oauth-encryption@1.2.1 (weak dependency)
  reload@1.1.11
  routepolicy@1.0.12
  service-configuration@1.0.11
  underscore@1.0.10
  url@1.1.0
  webapp@1.3.13

pauli:accounts-linkedin@2.1.2*

react-meteor-data@0.2.12
  ecmascript@0.4.1
  isobuild:isopack-2@1.0.0
  tmeasday:check-npm-versions@0.2.0
  tracker@1.0.11

reactive-var@1.0.11
  tracker@1.1.1

rzymek:moment-locale-el@2.14.1
  momentjs:moment@2.14.1

service-configuration@1.0.11
  accounts-base@1.2.14
  mongo@1.1.14

session@1.1.7
  ejson@1.0.13
  reactive-dict@1.1.8
  reload@1.1.11 (weak dependency)
  underscore@1.0.10

shell-server@0.2.3*

standard-minifier-css@1.3.4
  isobuild:minifier-plugin@1.0.0
  minifier-css@1.2.16

standard-minifier-js@2.1.0*

static-html@1.2.2
  caching-html-compiler@1.1.2
  ecmascript@0.5.8
  isobuild:compiler-plugin@1.0.0
  templating-tools@1.1.2
  underscore@1.0.9

tap:i18n@1.8.2
  aldeed:simple-schema@1.3.0
  cfs:http-methods@0.0.27
  check@1.0.3
  coffeescript@1.0.4
  isobuild:isopack-2@1.0.0
  jquery@1.0.1
  meteorspark:util@0.2.0
  raix:eventemitter@0.1.1
  session@1.0.3
  templating@1.0.8
  tracker@1.0.3
  underscore@1.0.1

themeteorchef:bert@2.1.2*

tracker@1.1.3

twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6
  jquery@1.0.1
```

## Edit 5

I also run the following command to scan all the installed packages for the locked dependency:

```
find ~/.meteor/packages  -type f -exec grep -H 'accounts-base@=1.3.0' {} +
```

And returns no result.

## Edit 6

I also provide alla the `accounts` related packages:

```
ls ~/.meteor/packages/ | grep "accounts"
accounts-base
accounts-facebook
accounts-github
accounts-google
accounts-meetup
accounts-meteor-developer
accounts-oauth
accounts-password
accounts-twitter
accounts-ui
accounts-ui-unstyled
accounts-weibo
pauli_accounts-linkedin
```

No on seems as clone.

Comment: What if you delete folder `.meteor/local` and run again to have Meteor rebuild it?

Comment: Still same prob.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.meteor/packages` file. Seems like you might have `accounts-base@=1.3.0` which pins it to this version. Replace it with just `accounts-base` and try the upgrade again.

Comment: It seems there is no reference to for `accounts-base@=1.3.0`

Comment: do you have a forked copy of accounts-base in your packages/ dir by any chance?

Comment: Do you mean `~/.meteor/packages/`?

Comment: I am not sure but I do not think so.

Comment: also try wiping your meteor .local... eg `mv .meteor/local/db ./; rm -fr .meteor/local; mkdir -p .meteor/local; mv db .meteor/local/` -- untested use at your own risk ;)